# How to attach an element in a list and write it to JSON?

Tags: python, json

1. Load JSON file to `aPool` list at beginning.

   ```
   def LoadPoolTemplate():
     sFilename = './pool_template.json'

     if os.path.exists(sFilename):
       with open(sFilename, 'r') as fJsonFile:
         aPool = json.load(fJsonFile)

     return aPool
   ```
2. Append `aTempJson` to `aPool[index]['devices']`

   ```
   def UpdateJSON(aPool, aDevList):
     sFilename = './device_template.json'
     if os.path.exists(sFilename):
       with open(sFilename, 'r') as fJsonFile:
         aTempJson = json.load(fJsonFile)
     else:
       print ("No such file names " + sFilename)

     for item in aDevList:
       aTempJson['id'] = item[1]
       aTempJson['atti']['high'] = item[2]

       for (i,pid) in enumerate(aPool):
         if pid['id'] == item[0]:
           aPool[i]['devices'].append(aTempJson)
           break
   ```
3. Update `aPool` list to JSON file

   ```
   def CreateDeviceJSON(aDevice):
     with open(gDevice, 'w') as fOutfile:
       json.dump(aDevice, fOutfile, indent=2)
   ```
4. Read list

   ```
   def ReadDeviceList():
     aDevList = []

     with open(gDevList, 'r') as fList:
       for line in fList:
         columns = line.strip().split(',')
         aDevList.append(columns)

     return aDevList
   ```
5. main function

   ```
   def main():
     aDevDist = []
     aDeviceJson = []

     aDeviceJson = LoadPoolTemplate()
     aDeviceList = ReadDeviceList()
     aDeviceJson = UpdateJSON(aDeviceJson, aDeviceList)

     CreateDeviceJSON(aDeviceJson)
   ```

I don't know why all the elements in devices list are the same, please help me.

JSON file output:

```json
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "devices": [
      {
         "atti": {
          "high": "190",
          "weight": "80"
        },
        "id": "Jordan"
      },
      {
         "atti": {
          "high": "190",
          "weight": "80"
        },
        "id": "Jordan"
      },
      {
         "atti": {
          "high": "190",
          "weight": "80"
        },
        "id": "Jordan"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "devices": [
      {
         "atti": {
          "high": "190",
          "weight": "80"
        },
        "id": "Jordan"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "id3",
    "devices": [
      {
         "atti": {
          "high": "190",
          "weight": "80"
        },
        "id": "Jordan"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Input source as following:

```
["id1", "apple", "167"]
["id1", "carter", "203"]
["id1", "jason", "188"]
["id2", "paul", "178"]
["id3", "Jordan", "190"]
```

Pool template

```
[
  {
    "id": "id1",
    "devices": [
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "devices": [
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "id3",
    "devices": [
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What is the `pool_template.json` file? I also think you need to add some "driver" code that calls the functions and reproduces the problem described.

Comment: @martineau I already update main function and pool_template.json. Please help me to take a look. thanks a lot.

Comment: use deepcopy to copy a list then fix it.

Comment: Yes: Make a copy, apply fixes to the copy, then append the copy with fixes to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
for item in aDevList:
    aTempJson['id'] = item[1]
    aTempJson['atti']['high'] = item[2]

    for (i,pid) in enumerate(aPool):
      if pid['id'] == item[0]:
        aPool[i]['devices'].append(aTempJson)
        break
```

you are modifying the **same** `aTempJson` dict and appending it to the list over and over. What you have to do is to create a new dict for each item.

Comment: I think I always update aTempJson dict again and again, so append it to the end of list. Is that right?

update contant

aTempJson['id'] = item[1], 
aTempJson['atti']['high'] = item[2]